# Generating java code from static variables in a class

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation

I have code that in essence looks like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static class FieldDefn {
        private String mName;
        private Class<?> mClass;

        public Field(String name, Class<?> clazz) {
            mClass = clazz;
            mName = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }
        public Class<?> getDataClass() {
            return mClass;
        }
    }

    public static class Data {
        private String mName;
        private ArrayList<FieldDefn> mFields;

        String getName() {
            return mName;
        }

        List<FieldDefn> getFields() {
            return mFields;
        }
        public Data addField(String name, Class<?> clazz) {
            mFields.add(new FieldDefn(name, clazz);
        }
    }

    private static Data mData1 = 
        new Data("D1")
            .addField("f1", Integer.class)
            .addField("f2", String.class);
}
```

And I would like to use Gradle (or java annotations, or something better) to auto-generate code that looks like this:

```
public class D1 extends AMoreFunctionalBaseClass {
    private Integer mF1;
    private String mF2;

    public Integer getF1() {
        return mF1;
    }

    public void setF1(Integer f1) {
        mF1 = f1;
    }

    public String getF2() {
        return mF2;
    }

    public void setF2(Integer f2) {
        mF2 = f2;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can get Java and/or gradle to generate this code for each such status definition? Perhaps via an annotation?

Annotations and gradle both seem to have code generation, but AFAICT from the examples I have seen, it seem to work on data available via data types, not actual data.

Comment: Once I used the Roaster library for a similar use case: https://github.com/forge/roaster
It has both a Parser API and a Code Generation API.

Comment: Will the "source class(es)" and the "generetated class(es)" be built in the same project/jar? Or separate project/jar

Comment: They will be in same project(s), but I have no specific requirement that they be in same or different jars. Same would seem logical, but not essential. I should also note that both 'mData1' and class D1 will be used.